# How can I avoid applying attr to all options of my choice field?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.7

Before Symfony 2.7, the `attr` value for a `choice` field applied only to the field itself, i.e. the `<select>` element that was rendered. I used this to apply classes to this element to style it.

In Symfony 2.7 this behavior was changed. Now, all `<option>` children of the `<select>` element also get the same attributes ([commit of the change](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/03efce1b568379eac21d880e427090e43035f505#diff-b56b980552f37a32080a57032805f34dL9)) and therefore classes.

---

For some clarification, let this be the code:

```
<?php echo $view['form']->widget($form['myField'], ['attr' => ['class' => "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"]]); ?>
```

Then this is the output of Symfony <=2.6:

```
<select class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name="myField">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

And this is the output of Symfony >= 2.7:

```
<select class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name="myField">
    <option value="1" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

---

The classes I apply are not suitable for `<option>` elements as they define borders and the like for the actual field. Note that these are classes defined by jQuery UI so I can't easily change their definition.

What is the easiest way to avoid applying these classes to all `<option>` elements of a `choice` field while still applying it to the `<select>` element?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. Cause I couldn't find anything in the UPGRADE-2.7 for it, and that functionality is what the `'choice_attr'` option is supposed to do.

Comment: @user2268997 Yes, I couldn't find anything either but looking at the code I linked it seems very intentional to me.

Comment: I don't know much about php templates, but it seems like 'attr' is resolved from `$choice` which is a `ChoiceView` instance, which is created by the `DefaultChoiceListFactory`, and the `choice_attr` option is passed to that factory in the `ChoiceType` definition.( if you don't supply own `ChoiceList`  ofcourse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comment about `choice_attr` by @user2268997 I found the related blog post [New in Symfony 2.7: Choice form type refactorization](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization)  which details the use of the (as of now undocumented) `choice_attr` option.

It seems Symfony merges the attributes in `choice_attr` with the ones in `attr` when rendering the field. This means we need to overwrite the `class` attribute in `choice_attr`.

I tried doing this in the code next to where I define `attr` but had no luck. It seems you need to do this in your form type definition. Here is an excerpt from my form after adding the `choice_attr` option:

```
namespace MyBundle\Form;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('roles',
            'entity',
            [
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Role',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_attr' => function () { return ["class" => ""]; }
            ]);
}
```

The result is as I had hoped. I will probably also refactor this to my own custom form type so I do not need to repeat it all over my bundle.

---

I have now decided to create a custom `choice` type with the desired behavior described above and use that one throughout my application.

Here is my choice type:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ChoiceNoOptAttrType extends ChoiceType {
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefault("choice_attr", function () { return ["class" => ""]; });
    }
}
```

I did not feel like refactoring all my existing forms to use this new type, so instead I opted to replace the Symfony-provided choice type with mine. This can be achieved by modifying the service configuration for the `choice` form type. To do this, I created a compiler pass for my bundle.

Further reading: [Creating a Compiler Pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-a-compiler-pass)

```
namespace MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class MyCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition("form.type.choice");
        $definition->setClass('MyBundle\Form\ChoiceNoOptAttrType');
    }
}
```

Now all that is left to do is register the compiler pass in the bundle.

Further reading:  [How to Work with Compiler Passes in Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html)

```
namespace MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MyCompilerPass;

class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new MyCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

And this is it. Now all my `choice` fields are using my custom class which makes sure that the CSS class set in `attr` is not propagated to my `<option>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler solution, but you might want to take a look at [Form Themes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes). Override the Template for choice_widget_options so that the classes are not applied to the option tags.

```
{%- block choice_widget_options -%}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {%- if choice is iterable -%}
            <optgroup label="{{ choice_translation_domain is sameas(false) ? group_label : group_label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            </optgroup>
        {%- else -%}
            {% set attr = choice.attr %}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}" {# DELETE THIS PART: {{ block('attributes') }}#}{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice_translation_domain is sameas(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_options -%}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't use twig templates.

Comment: Then you can override the php template, I think.

Comment: Thanks, this also came to my mind. However, I had hoped I could skip overwriting this (rather complex) template as I would likely have to maintain it for future versions.